# Hibernate: Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I'm using hibernate for desktop application and I'm getting this exception:

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 20; Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.
```

This is my configuration XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_hibernate</property>

        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And this is the mapping XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="model.Employee" table="employee">
     <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the employee detail.
     </meta>
     <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
     </id>
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="salary" column="salary" type="double"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Looks like your DOCTYPE definition in mapping XML is wrong, it should be `<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">`, notice 3.0 between `DTD` and `//EN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd` I've in `hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar`, your DOCTYPE declaration in `Employee.hbm.xml` should be like below

`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">`

Instead of

`<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">`

Notice there's a `3.0` between `DTD` and `//EN`